# acer laptop left control key not recognized ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I recently bought a used Acer Aspire-ES1-511 with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.  I found that the left Ctrl key wasn't working, but the right one does work.  In `xev` I found the left key showed FocusOut and FocusIn events when it was pressed, and the right one (correctly) had KeyPress and KeyRelease events.  I looked at the shortcut settings, couldn't find anything.  I looked at the keyboard configuration, couldn't find anything.  I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, that didn't make any difference.  I looked for the 'Show Keyboard Layout' utility, it's nowhere to be found, in fact there also isn't a menu option in the title bar for changing the keyboard language as mentioned at https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/configure-keyboard-ubuntu/  I've tried resetting all of the keyboard shortcuts, that doesn't make a difference.  If I shell over to a different virtual terminal using  e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F3, *that* key combination is recognized, and Ctrl-C works as expected at the prompt.

Pretty clearly *something* in the GUI is modifying the behavior of the left Ctrl key, but I haven't been able to identify *what* is doing it.

For the left Ctrl key, `xev` shows this output:

```
FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

For the right Ctrl key, `xev` shows this output:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x13e, subw 0x0, time 3247932, (96,-19), root:(1249,175),
    state 0x0, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x13e, subw 0x0, time 3248126, (96,-19), root:(1249,175),
    state 0x4, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Other information:

```
$ kbdcontrol
kbdcontrol: command not found

$ console-setup
console-setup: command not found

$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="acer_laptop"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"

$ xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)

$ uname -a
Linux acer-Aspire-ES1-511 4.15.0-54-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What other information should I provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After battling with this problem (off and on) for three weeks, I stumbled across the root cause today.  After installing `dconf-tools` so I could run `dconf-editor`, I looked through `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` and found two assignments were not in their default state:  `toggle-shaded` was set to `'<Ctrl><Alt>s'` (IIRC), and `move-to-workspace-12` was set to `'Control_L'`.  When I deleted the `move-to-workspace-12` assignment, the left Control key immediately started working correctly.

Note that the `toggle-shaded` assignment is a properly constructed mapping, but the `move-to-workspace-12` one is not:  I think someone intended to assign `<Ctrl>L'` to that binding, but when they set it to `'Control_L'` instead, they broke the keyboard.